# Java: NullPointerException caused by class definition?

Tags: java, swing, nullpointerexception

I'm getting the following NullPointerException:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.foo.JawsFileChooser.a(SourceFile:28)
    at com.foo.JawsFileChooser$1.actionPerformed(SourceFile:91)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2018)
    [...snip...]
```

when users click a button in my app and follow a certain set of steps.  But Line 28 in JawsFileChooser.java is the line which defines the class:

```
public class JawsFileChooser extends JPanel implements SwingConstants, DebugConstants {
```

.  What could I take a look at to figure out why this is happening?

thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Add the a() method, it might be outdated byte code?

Comment: It just looks like bad line number reporting.  I would take a look at the `a(...)` method of `JawsFileChooser` and see if you can figure it out yourself.  Or else debug it...

Comment: Post your code from `JawsFileChooser` around the lines on the stack trace

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What could I take a look at to figure out why this is happening?

You could take a look at `SourceFile:28`, it is part of `com.foo.JawsFileChooser.a` and dereferencing a reference that is `null`

EDIT: 
I have seen the first line of class reported in stacktrace in presence of anonymous inner classes. For example the following code

```
 1 import java.util.concurrent.*;
 2 
 3 class An {
 4 
 5  private String foo()
 6  {
 7      return "foo";
 8  }
 9  
10  public static void main(String[] args) {
11      final An an = null;
12      (new Callable<String>() {
13          public String call() {
14              return an.foo();
15          }
16      }).call();
17  }
18 }
```

Results in

```
javac -g An.java && java -cp . An
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at An.access$000(An.java:3)
    at An$1.call(An.java:14)
    at An.main(An.java:12)
```

The synthesized method name is printed but the line number is similar to your case. I would look at `com.foo.JawsFileChooser$1.actionPerformed(SourceFile:91)`

Comment: In his post he indicates that line 28 is the class definition.

Comment: the problem was indeed triggered by an anonymous ActionListener attached to a JButton.  Once the listener was explicitly created and instantiated, I was able to get a stack trace that made sense.  Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Don't always rely on the line numbers!
And even if you do, have a look at line 91 as well -

at com.foo.JawsFileChooser$1.actionPerformed(SourceFile:91)

Answer (score 0):

Odds are good that within the actionPerformed(...) method of the button, it references a selection, which may not exist (or may have no contents).  Did you write your code to handle these conditions?  If not, perhaps you trying to do / verify something against a null pointer.